# What data type in java to put value more than 64 bit, excluding BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

What data type could I use in java to put in a value of more than 64 bit, **Except `BigInteger`**?

Comment: How about `BigDecimal`?

Comment: What's wrong with BigInteger?

Comment: You could roll your own type, but why? BigInteger already does everything you may need. And it is a well tested and well optimized type, unlike something you write on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use BigInteger class you should declare your own class that uses a byte array to hold bytes of you number.It is so difficult.

Comment: BigInteger internally uses int arrays. But why all the trouble? Implementing a similar type of one's own is hard, and BigInteger is well tested and well optimized. Very hard to beat that.

Comment: `BigInteger` uses a `String` to hold its digits. There is no other way to define a big number than 64 bits except `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: BigInteger does **not** use a String to hold its digits, it uses an `int []`. Just look at the code.

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi: BigInteger uses an array of int, not a string. And BigDecimal is just a BigInteger with an added scale, i.e. internally it uses a BigInteger (for values > long).